# Introductory Java math program returning 0

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to work on a program challenge that takes an input of Air, Water, or Steel, and shows the speed of sound traveled in feet in Java.

My driver code looks like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class driver
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String type;
int distance;
int time = 0;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Input one of the following- Air, water, or steel.");
        type = keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.print("Input distance in feet");
        distance = keyboard.nextInt();

        speedofsound sound = new speedofsound(distance);

        if (type.equals("Air"))
    time = sound.getSpeedInAir();
        System.out.println(time);
        if (type.equals("Water"))
    time = sound.getSpeedInWater();

        if (type.equals("Steel"))
    time = sound.getSpeedInSteel();

        System.out.println("The time it would take for"  + type + "to travel" + distance + "feet is" + time);
 }
}
```

and the Class looks like this

```
public class speedofsound {// class stating
private int distance;//distance integer
private int time;

public speedofsound (int d)
{
    distance = d; // from driver pass over dist in ft, 
}

public int getSpeedInAir()

{
return  (distance / 1100);

}
public int getSpeedInWater()

{
time = distance / 4900;
return time;
}
public int getSpeedInSteel()

{
time = distance / 16400;
return time;
 }
}
```

When I execute this in the console I get "Input one of the following- Air, water, or steel.Air
Input distance in feet50
0
The time it would take forAirto travel50feet is0"
No matter what I input, I keep getting 0. Whats up?

Comment: What integer value do you expect `50 / 1100` to be?

Comment: This is integer division, try to float the divisor or the dividend.